# Python intra-package imports failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

This is my project structure

```
|--project/
    |--__init__.py
    |--package1/
        |--__init__.py
        |--module1.py
    |--package2/
        |--__init__.py
        |--module2.py
```

In `module1.py` I do `from project.package2 import module2`

The output: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named project`

Relative imports don't work either.

I am using Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20 and have tried with or without `__init__` files.

Any ideas why the way the official docs explain how to do imports doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried `from package2 import module2`? `__init__.py` files are mandatory.

Comment: No it is not working. `No module named package2`

Comment: what is the content of your `__init__.py` file? Have a look at: [How to make python packages](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-your-first-python-package/)

Comment: It is empty. I am thinking maybe there is some problem with my sys.path list

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was actually the `sys.path`

When importing a package the interpreter searches through the directories on sys.path list looking for it as per the documentation says.

The solution to this problem is to add my package's path to my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or append my path directly to `sys.path`